# Linking UML Diagrams - What are the different possibilities and how to specify in a tool independent wa

Tags: uml, diagramming

UML 2.x has 14 diagram types - grouped into structural and behavioral diagrams. For a system modelled in UML, there is inter-linking between diagrams, for example:
A class with a state variable should have a corresponding state-machine diagram which models its behavior.
Similarly, the life-line in sequence diagram is an instance of a class: usually shown as :.
What are the other links possible between the 14 diagrams?

Is there a tool independent way of specifying these?

Are these linkages exported in a standard way in the XMI output file, if XMI export is supported?

Answer (score 0):

In UML2 you can now create almost any model element in any diagram. I mean that you can have structural elements inside the same diagram. 
[alt text http://www.forum-omondo.com/download/file.php?id=194&mode=view](http://www.forum-omondo.com/download/file.php?id=194&mode=view)

Having said that you can also use the EclipseUML2 editor which is open source. You create manually your model and for example create a State then a child Class. Once created you open the model with a compatible UML tool and drag and drop inside an empty diagram what has been manually model. You will get a graphical representation.

I do it every day with Omondo EclipseUML Helios and it works really well. I have previously tried RSA 6.5 and it was also possible. My graphical diagram allows me to create as many as needed views from my model. I can manipulate my model with the editor or with the diagram. Really cool !!